# Debugging Source Indexed Software with Visual Studio is a pain

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm responsible for some internal tools and I want to make debugging them as easy as possible on client machines. We used to ship with full source code and debugging information and built them in exactly the same location as the typical client install path. This made debugging extremely easy.

We have now moved to using Windows Installer to deploy our software, and we symbol serve the debugging information and source index the pdbs.

This now makes debugging a right pain, as for each client I want to debug, I have to change several options in Visual Studio to enable source indexing and add a file into a Visual Studio directory to stop it complaining about running the source control commands. I also can't search the source code easily as the files are only extracted on demand.

Is there a better way we can do this? I have tried hosting archives of the source code on a network share, and using symbolic links to alias the network share with the local hard drive on build, but that requires UNC paths, which the VS2008 manifest tool can't cope with.

We also have used an undocumented linker option (/sourcemap) which does let you redirect all the source paths to an arbitrary location, but this does not work for .Net apps (as that option is availble for link.exe)

Even if we supplied the source code with the installation, the paths in the PDB would still be wrong.

Is there any way to patch a PDB (supported or unsupported by Microsoft) to redirect the paths elsewhere?

Answer (score -1):

I can't help you with a direct answer, but perhaps I can inspire you with a meta-answer.

Debugging in a production environment is fundamentally wrong. Others have tried it (Netscape comes to mind) and failed miserably. For something like tools, it's even more pertinent to ensure proper function through solid unit testing, and automated tests for your release. You can setup your tests to work with different qualities of input (from perfect-textbook to medium to poor to awful) and quantities (i.e. test limits). There's a lot of [books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=unit+test&x=0&y=0) available on testing and particularly unit testing.

I understand it's tough getting out of the day-to-day to make something like this work (I'm neck deep in it myself), but it's one of the sanest, if not *the only* sane way out.